# JQuery: Saber si se ha desmarcado o marcado un checkbox

Tags: jquery

Tengo el codigo que se activa cuando cambia el checkbox, pero eso no es lo que busco, busco saber si se a marcado o desmarcado el checkbox para sumar o restar su value

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {

            tiempoRestante = $(".totalMin").html() - $(this).val()
            $(".totalMin").empty()

            if (tiempoRestante >= 0)
                $(".totalMin").append(tiempoRestante)
            convertidorMinutos()
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Usando el método jQuery `prop()`**

El método jQuery prop() proporciona una forma simple y efectiva de rastrear el estado actual de un checkbox.

```js
if($('checkbox-selector').prop("checked") == true) {
    console.log("Checkbox is checked.");
}
else if($('checkbox-selector').prop("checked") == false) {
    console.log("Checkbox is unchecked.");
}
```

**Usando el selector jQuery `:checked`**

También puede usar jQuery y el selector `checked` para verificar el estado del checkbox.

```js
if($('checkbox-selector').is(":checked")) {
    console.log("Checkbox is checked.");
}
else if($('checkbox-selector').is(":not(:checked)")) {
    console.log("Checkbox is unchecked.");
}
```